# Convert DateTime to LongDateString in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to convert the DateTime property,

```
<Label Text="{Binding PaymentDate}"></Label>

<Label Text="{Binding PaymentDate, StringFormat=D}"></Label>
```

Please let me know what string format to use. The above logic didn't work.

```
<Label Text="{Binding PaymentDate, StringFormat=D}"></Label>
```

Comment: what "above logic" are you talking about?  You didn't post any code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of option:

Option 1:

You do a String format in the XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding ActualDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}'}" Font="15,Bold" />
```

Option 2:

In you model have a string property e.g. DateFormatted which is a GET property that returns the string formatted representation of your Actual Date property:

```
public string DateFormatted { get { return ActualDate.ToLongDateString(); } }
```